# How to create a blurry background in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I want to create a background like this:[image]

But gets like this (notice the spots and trails):
[image]

I tried with different color modes/bits per channel. It's always like that. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got:

[image]

1. Press X to set colors to black & white
2. Filter -> Render -> Clouds
3. Create a Levels adjustment layer, and move the slider to the right to increase contrast.
4. Select the Levels adjustment layer, and press CTRL+E to apply to the background layer
5. Filter -> Blur -> Gaussian Blur, and move it right until you reach the desired blurriness.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How to create levels layer style?

Comment: Sorry, it was an adjustment layer.
`Layer -> New Adjustment Layer -> Levels`